# scrollTop get each pixel

Tags: javascript, pixel, scrolltop

When I use the function scrollTop to get the amount of pixels of the top I receive 1, 4, 20,... depending on the speed that I am scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(position);
)};
```

I am building a site were I need to get each pixel. This because I am checking when a certain position-value is showing. For example:

```
if(position === 1200){
    // do something
}
```

Now this is not possible with the values I receive of the scrollTop function. Now I'am using this code below which make it possible to calculate each pixel, but this is only working smooth when the site is not to heigh. If the site is more then 3000px of height, it will begin to jitter because it takes to lang to calculate the pixel.

```
var viewportFirstPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var inc;

    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var viewportNewPosition = $(document).scrollTop();

    if(viewportNewPosition > viewportFirstPosition){
       inc=1;
    }
    else{
       inc=-1;
    }

    while(viewportFirstPosition !== viewportNewPosition){
        viewportFirstPosition += inc;
        console.log(viewportFirstPosition); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can do it differently? Without the jitter :)
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of exactly equal, try using an interval.

Comment: You can't. People scroll faster than pixel-by-pixel.

Comment: why ur not used `offset()`?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** get the `scrollTop()` of each pixel, that's because the function takes some milliseconds to work and return the value (depending on the machine it's running on), and if you scroll with an high speed it will not be able to check all the pixels.

I suggest you to change your control statement to this one:

```
if (position >= 1200){
    // do something
}
```

Getting the position of *exactly 1200 pixels* is nearly impossible.

Even if you had got the best PC being able to detect each pixel, on slower devices it will never work, so the only solution is to check *around 1200px* or *more than 1200px*, but not *exactly 1200px*.